# System Requirement to train BERT model

Tags: nlp, recommender-system, bert

1. How much Hardware is required to train it well?(My current PC specs: 8GB RAM, i5 2 core Processor, Standard GPU (No work going on GPU))
2. I have a dataset of approx 1lakh records.Is it is necessary to train BERT model on such large records or it will give better results on less records as well?
3. Is BERT capable to classify unidentified text which is not present in train data but in test data?